# Calculate Total Time Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I am using a sharepoint to list to track some data. I have a column called Training Start Time which is a date/time field. Then I have another column called Training End Time. In order to get the total duration, I am using a calculated field with the following code

```
=TEXT([Training End Time]-[Training Start Time],"h:mm")
```

This will be me the total duration. What I can't figure out how to do, is make a total field which gives me all the totals added up. So if someone enters 5 hours and another person adds in 3 hours, the field I need would give as an example 8 hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it programmatically. A similar solution that uses JSLink is present here 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30317.sharepoint-2013-displaying-sum-for-calculated-column-in-a-list-view-using-jslink.aspx

AFAIK, you cannot do this OOTB solution.